# Breadcrumbs not displaying on Product Page Magento-2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4, breadcrumbs

After upgrade breadcrumbs from product page disappear. As suggested, I have updated my **`breadcrumbs.js`** but still not showing. Only displaying code like below.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" data-mage-init='{
    "breadcrumbs": {
        "categoryUrlSuffix": ".html",
        "useCategoryPathInUrl": 0,
        "product": "Aquasure Dash Series Countertop Drinking  Water System with Micro-Ceramic Filtration"
    }
  }'>
</div>
```

Comment: check console log, something is stopping Magento JS to render /read `data-mage-init`

Comment: There is no any error in my console.

Comment: Are you use default theme or custom theme?

Comment: I am using a custom theme.

Comment: is there others `data-mage-init` in your browsers HTML? Actually, Magento remove that attribute if successfully run function/JS which calling in `data-mage-init`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same issue but its resolved. Please check the below link.

[Breadcrumbs not working on Product Page Magento 2.2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228848/breadcrumbs-not-working-on-product-page-magento-2-2-4/229007)

Comment: I am not creating a module but using the same code in Magento block(breadcrumbs.php) and template(breadcrumbs.phtml) but not working.

Comment: Are you using custom theme or any purchased theme?

Comment: I am using purchased theme.

Comment: Did you check the demo of that purchased theme to confirm whether its working there or not?

Comment: It was working earlier version but after the upgrade, it is not working.

Comment: Did you install this module it works for me?  Install it and rung the required commands. https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: Yes, this extension worked for me. https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Upvote please.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, That extension not working properly, if we navigate to any product detail page, the category is showing invalid, ex, i navigated from men to some product, but in detail page of that product, men category not showing

Answer (score 9):

It's still possible to activate the classic breadcrumb. Just put these lines into your layout-xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs" />
```

1. The first line sets the template which is used on non-product-pages.
2. The second line instantiates the given block class which adds the breadcrumb-paths to the first block.

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite the Plugin

[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="custom_product_breadcrumbs" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View as MagentoView;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class View
{

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $product;
    /**
     * @var StoreManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $collection;
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $resultPage;


    /**
     * View constructor.
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param PageFactory $resultPage
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManager $storeManager,
        Registry $registry,
        Collection $collection,
        PageFactory $resultPage)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->resultPage = $resultPage;
    }

    public function afterExecute(MagentoView $subject, $result)
    {
        if(!$result instanceof Page){
            return $result;
        }

        $resultPage = $this->resultPage->create();
        $breadcrumbsBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        if(!$breadcrumbsBlock || !isset($breadcrumbsBlock)){
            return $result;

        }
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'home',
            [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                'link' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
            ]
        );

        try {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $result;
        }

        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set($product->getName());

        if(null == $product->getCategory() || null == $product->getCategory()->getPath()){
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'cms_page',
                [
                    'label' => $product->getName(),
                    'title' => $product->getName(),
                ]
            );
            return $result;
        }

        $categories = $product->getCategory()->getPath();
        $categoriesids = explode('/', $categories);

        $categoriesCollection = null;
        try {
            $categoriesCollection = $this->collection
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $categoriesids))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('include_in_menu')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $result;
        }

        foreach ($categoriesCollection->getItems() as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
                $categoryId = $category->getId();
                $path = [
                    'label' => $category->getName(),
                    'link' => $category->getUrl() ? $category->getUrl() : ''
                ];
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('category' . $categoryId, $path);
            }
        }

        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'cms_page',
            [
                'label' => $product->getName(),
                'title' => $product->getName(),
            ]
        );

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');

            if (!$this->product->getId()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Failed to initializing product'));
            }
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create file:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js
```

Add this jquery

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/model/breadcrumb-list'
], function ($, breadcrumbList) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul'
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            _render: function () {
                this._appendCatalogCrumbs();
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * Append category and product crumbs.
             *
             * @private
             */
            _appendCatalogCrumbs: function () {
                var categoryCrumbs = this._resolveCategoryCrumbs();

                categoryCrumbs.forEach(function (crumbInfo) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(crumbInfo);
                });

                if (this.options.product) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(this._getProductCrumb());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Resolve categories crumbs.
             *
             * @return Array
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryCrumbs: function () {
                var menuItem = this._resolveCategoryMenuItem(),
                    categoryCrumbs = [];

                if (menuItem !== null && menuItem.length) {
                    categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));

                    while ((menuItem = this._getParentMenuItem(menuItem)) !== null) {
                        categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));
                    }
                }

                return categoryCrumbs;
            },

            /**
             * Returns crumb data.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {
                var categoryId,
                    categoryName,
                    categoryUrl;

                categoryId = /(\d+)/i.exec(menuItem.attr('id'))[0];
                categoryName = menuItem.text();
                categoryUrl = menuItem.attr('href');

                return {
                    'name': 'category',
                    'label': menuItem.text(),
                    'link': menuItem.attr('href'),
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Returns product crumb.
             *
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getProductCrumb: function () {
                return {
                    'name': 'product',
                    'label': this.options.product,
                    'link': '',
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Find parent menu item for current.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _getParentMenuItem: function (menuItem) {
                var classes,
                    classNav,
                    parentClass,
                    parentMenuItem = null;

                if (!menuItem) {
                    return null;
                }

                classes = menuItem.parent().attr('class');
                classNav = classes.match(/(nav\-)[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)+/gi);

                if (classNav) {
                    classNav = classNav[0];
                    parentClass = classNav.substr(0, classNav.lastIndexOf('-'));

                    if (parentClass.lastIndexOf('-') !== -1) {
                        parentMenuItem = $(this.options.menuContainer).find('.' + parentClass + ' > a');
                        parentMenuItem = parentMenuItem.length ? parentMenuItem : null;
                    }
                }

                return parentMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category menu item.
             *
             * Tries to resolve category from url or from referrer as fallback and
             * find menu item from navigation menu by category url.
             *
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryMenuItem: function () {
                var categoryUrl = this._resolveCategoryUrl(),
                    menu = $(this.options.menuContainer),
                    categoryMenuItem = null;

                if (categoryUrl && menu.length) {
                    categoryMenuItem = menu.find('a[href="' + categoryUrl + '"]');
                }

                return categoryMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category url.
             *
             * @return {String}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                        this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```

and after run deploy Command:

```
1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug (actually a feature) that only comes up when you upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4 and have a non-standard topmenu (yes, you read right): https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15490

Workaround that worked for me: [Magento2: breadcrumbs disappeared from product page after upgrading to 2.2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227232/magento2-breadcrumbs-disappeared-from-product-page-after-upgrading-to-2-2-4)

Comment: I already tried both but somehow it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

yes I saw that the issue caused by the cache when someone opens the product from the search or from a custom widget the product page will be opened without category breadcrumbs and as well will be cached as it