# Magento2 Improper Breadcrumb On Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2.2, breadcrumbs

I'm using a custom theme for Magento2.2.4 & also used Magento Migration tool.

On product detail page, currently, breadcrumb format is (please visit on below link).

**e.g-** http://nimb.ws/V8paZS

But the right format should be:-

**e.g-** http://nimb.ws/ARX7YG

Comment: You landed to product detail page direct or via search page that wise it is not showing category hierarchy,  if you go via  category page you will see the category hierarchy in breadcrumb this is default behavior, more help need please let us know. :)

Comment: thanks for the input, no I'm visiting the product via the category page.

Comment: just try this valid answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227232/magento2-breadcrumbs-disappeared-from-product-page-after-upgrading-to-2-2-4 let me know the feedback